# Get a character from a position in dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How do I get the first character of a string in dart flutter.

For example,a string having a value "Hello World" should return only "H".
I am fetching data from my firestore database.
My code is:

```
searchByName(String searchField) {
  return Firestore.instance
      .collection('posts')
      .where('description',
      isEqualTo: searchField.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase())
      .getDocuments();
}
```

I want to get the first letter from the data that I recieve from 'description' field in above code.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can do this by getting the first element of the String (indicated by index 0):

```
'${mystring[0]}'
```

example:

```
  String mystring = 'Hello World';

  print('${mystring[0]}');
```

in this case you will get as an output:

```
H
```

Comment: hey Jorgesys, Your code actually works but It was ,my bad that I couldnot clarify my question. I have recently edited my question. Please let me know if you can help

Comment: Sure we can help you but please update your question, read [ask] and add more details.

Comment: Hi @Jorgesys I would like to inform you that your answer is incorrect. You can check yourself easily at https://dartpad.dartlang.org/dart

Comment: @YanDatsiuk If I use String s = 'this is a string';
  print s[0];   as you suggested I get an error "Error: 'print' isn't a type.  print s[0];", but if I use the method described in my answer:    String s = 'this is a string';
  print('${s[0]}');   I get "t" as result, why my answer is incorrect? :-|

Answer (score 59):

To get first character of string you should use method [substring](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/String/substring.html)
Example:

```
word.substring(0,1);
```

Comment: How to get first letter of second word
example : - "hello flutter"

output will be "f"

Comment: Split it and get first char from the second item of array

Answer (score 7):

For Perform Searching in Firebase Document Field This Will Work

```
void main() {
  String mystring = 'Hello World';
  String search = ''; 
  
  for (int i=0;i<mystring.length;i++){
  search += mystring[i];
  print(search);
 } 
}
```

Output

```
H
He
Hel
Hell
Hello
Hello 
Hello W
Hello Wo
Hello Wor
Hello Worl
Hello World
```

For me this Works.

Comment: Gives an error ```RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..10: 11```

Comment: can you update it?

Comment: ok i updated that

Comment: Thanks, for updating. By the way, how is this method of splitting a string called? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Needed to get first `n` values rather than just one, and kept getting `Value not in range: 10` error using substring, here's a helper function to cut a string down to the first x characters:

```
  //* Limits given string, adds '..' if necessary
  static String shortenName(String nameRaw, {int nameLimit = 10, bool addDots = false}) {
    //* Limiting val should not be gt input length (.substring range issue)
    final max = nameLimit < nameRaw.length ? nameLimit : nameRaw.length;
    //* Get short name
    final name = nameRaw.substring(0, max);
    //* Return with '..' if input string was sliced
    if (addDots && nameRaw.length > max) return name + '..'; 
    return name;
  }
```

Usage:

```
    return Helpers.shortenName('Sausage', nameLimit: 5);
```